# Outline gradient - css

Tags: html, css

I need help with adding gradient to outline. I can't larger height because positioning wouldn't work right. Is there any way? I tried to merge this code with gradient class but gradient worked only for that 1px height. Any suggestions?

```
    height: 1px !important;
    background: #D3D3D3;    
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    outline: 3px solid #D3D3D3;
```

Thanks,
Jan

http://jsfiddle.net/he703uzv/

Comment: We need more code and jsfiddle

Comment: Does it have to be an `outline` rather than a `border`? If not you should look into using [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image).

Comment: You can also check http://jsfiddle.net/necolas/vqnk9/

Comment: post all the relevant code to help better

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/examples/GradientBorder/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/qryouad1/

Comment: you may find [Create a border gradient for each of the 4 borders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28406174/create-a-border-gradient-for-each-of-the-4-borders) helpful

Comment: It have to be outline. Here is jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/he703uzv/

Comment: This question is not a duplicate. It asks for an outline gradient, not a border gradient.

Answer (score 2):

```css
.outline-border { 
    width: 400px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-top: 10px solid #47c465;
    border-bottom:10px solid #00deff;
    background-image: 
        linear-gradient(#47c465, #00deff),
        linear-gradient(#47c465, #00deff)
    ;
    background-size:10px 100%;
    background-position:0 0, 100% 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="outline-border">Hello World!</div>
```

See Outline Gradient.

Comment: I have to use  outline: ; , tried with border but other things like responsive, position, etc. wont work correct